# cohomology ring of a subspace of real projective spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, projective-space, cw-complexes

I learned $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^n;\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2[a]/(a^{n+1})$, $|a|=1$, in topology class, when studying cell complex and cohomology.

Now I want to find the cohomology ring $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^{n+2}\setminus \mathbb{R}P^{n};\mathbb{Z}_2)$ and $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^{n+2}\setminus \mathbb{R}P^{n};\mathbb{Z})$.  How to get it? Any references? Thanks.

Note: I think $H^1(\mathbb{R}P^{n+2}\setminus \mathbb{R}P^{n};\mathbb{Z}_2)$ should be nontrivial. But 
$\mathbb{R}P^{n+2}\setminus \mathbb{R}P^{n}$ only has 3 nontrivial cells of dimension $n$, $n+1$, $n+2$. Why?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but since $RP^{n-1}$ is a disk glued along $RP^{n-2}$, the restriction to the old $n-1$ skeleton is just a disk. From there on it is easy.

Comment: Dear Prof. Dan, how to continue to get the cup product structure? Thanks so much!

Comment: By properties of cup product, you get the cup product structure for free if the underlying graded module is easy enough.